# How to set up a sendmail relay using HP-UX 11.x

Tags: email, smtp, relay, hp-ux

I need to setup and HP-UX 11.23 system as a mail relay to collect mail from other internal HP-UX servers and relay them to the MS Excahnge operated smtp relay for delivering internet bound mail to the outsid world.

In the past, all my servers had direct port 25 access to the smtp relay, so adding the line

DSsmtp.mydomain.com

where smtp.mydomain.com my exchange gateway, sufficed.

Now, I need an intermediary. And it has to be HP-UX. How do I need to modify sendmail.cf and (if necessary) which other file(s) to accomplish my purpose ?

```
HPUX_srv_1  --->  HPUX_srv_2  --->  smtp.mydomain.com   --->  Big-bad-internet
   |                                       |
   +----------- can not connect -----------+
```

Thanks